# Q: Basic PowerShell Script Issue: “Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline”

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I know well, this issue has already been discussed a lot. But even though I am unable to solve it myself, since I only use powershell scripting rarely...

I have the following commands, that I need to execute as a ".bat" file. If I just execute it within a command window, all works fine. But if I execute it within a ".bat" file, I get the error from the title...

```
powershell -Command "&{$devices = gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice |%{[wmi] ($_.Dependent)}|select DeviceID;$devices.DeviceID | %{Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\$_"}| select FriendlyName,HardwareID}"
```

Within the ".bat" file I added an additional line with "pause", that seems not to be the cause of the problem...

I would be very happy if someone more advanced in scripting could tell me what 1 to 10 chars need to be added/changed in the command to make it work ;-)

Big thanks in advance!!!

Regards,
Erik

Comment: You need to escape the `"` around `HKLM:...` (double them): `""HKM:\...""`

Comment: Escape the nested double-quotes enclosing the registry key, with a **```\```** character, like this `\"HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\$_\"`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! But escaping the double-quotes by bashlash does not work. If i escape the double-quotes by doubling them it makes a difference, but now I get these errors:

    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Comment: Just to add, I see no reason why you are using `"&{}"` rather than `""` or `^&{}` why make things longer when they don't need to be

Comment: Thanks for all the help. The solutions are all great. The reason why I seem to make things more complicated as needed is simply that I am not very advanced in using powershell :-)

Comment: @ErikHörmann, I have rolled back your latest edit, please do not add SOLVED to the title of your question, _(or in fact add solutions to it)_. There is a correct way to indicate that an answer has solved your issue, and that is to mark that answer as accepted, by clicking on the large grayed out check mark to its left.

Answer (score 3):

Based upon [your response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68018465/q-basic-powershell-script-issue-expressions-are-only-allowed-as-the-first-ele/68024274#comment120229024_68018465) to [my initial comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68018465/q-basic-powershell-script-issue-expressions-are-only-allowed-as-the-first-ele/68024274#comment120223224_68018465), the reason for that error is that you're using the `%` alias for `ForEach-Object`, and in a batch file, the `%` character needs to be escaped using another `%` character.

Including the nested double-quote escaping with backward slashes, I've already advised, your resulting command would therefore be:

```sh
powershell -Command "&{$devices = gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice |%%{[wmi] ($_.Dependent)}|select DeviceID;$devices.DeviceID | %%{Get-ItemProperty -Path \"HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\$_\"}| select FriendlyName,HardwareID}"
```

Tested result example:

[image]

---

If I was doing this I'd probably have done it a little differently:

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command^
 "((Get-CimInstance Win32_USBControllerDevice).Dependent).DeviceID |"^
 "ForEach-Object {"^
    "Get-ItemProperty -Path \"HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\$_\""^
 "} | Select-Object FriendlyName, HardwareID"
```

And using shortened commands/aliases:

```sh
PowerShell -NoP "((gcim Win32_USBControllerDevice).Dependent).DeviceID|%%{gp \"HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\$_\"}|Select FriendlyName,HardwareID"
```

Comment: Damn...you're genius. I am every time impressed how powerful PS can be - "IF" you know how to use it...big thanks for all the help in here. Great community!!!